# Series' object has no attribute 'get_monthly_returns_heatmap' problem

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as ply
import quandl

start=pd.to_datetime('2012.01.01')
end=pd.datetime.now()       #pd.to_datetime('2019.07.20')

btc= quandl.get("BITFINEX/BTCUSD.4",start_date=start,end_date=end, authtoken="F51kbhqij4J1o73V5vXT")

returns =btc.Last.pct_change()

import monthly_returns_heatmap as mrh

heatmap = returns.get_monthly_returns_heatmap()
```

But i got the result of 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_monthly_returns_heatmap' problem " Despite i convert returns into a dataframe, it did not work.  The wrapper i used is sourced from 'https://pypi.org/project/monthly-returns-heatmap/"

The purpose is to generate a history monthly returns for bitcoin price into a table.

Comment: When you say _I convert returns into a dataframe_, do you mean you tried it and it still didn’t work, or your current code does the conversion? _purpose is to generate a history month returns for bitcoin price into a table_ That’s not what the current issue is about though, right? That library is just a convenience for plotting.

Comment: i have successfully converted the price into the return data and turned it into the data frame but i cant use the library to turn it into a monthly return table

Comment: Again, what does _i cant use the library to turn it into a monthly return table_ mean? If something has changed, it might be worthwhile to edit your post.